# Python: "as" keyword for shorthand

Tags: python, iteration, shorthand

Simple question: is it possible to assign shorthand references when iterating in Python, like this (which doesn't work):

```
class SomeClass:
    class_dict = {0:0,1:1,2:2,3:3}

newClass = SomeClass()

for n in newClass.class_dict as thedict: # assigning a shorthand reference "thedict" to newClass.class_dict
    print(thedict[n])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want this (iterate the key/value pair as `n, o` using `iteritems()`):

```
class SomeClass:
    class_dict = {0:0,1:1,2:2,3:3}

newClass = SomeClass()

for n, o in newClass.class_dict.iteritems():
    print(o)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want, thanks.  Not the shorthand I was thinking of, but the shorthand I need all the same.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you wanted to pursue the original idea, you can simply assign the class_dict to a new name. Any changes made to either dictionary affect both as they are really the same dictionary in memory because of aliasing.

Eg.

```
class SomeClass:
class_dict = {0:0,1:1,2:2,3:3}

newClass = SomeClass()

thedict = newClass.class_dict

for n in thedict:
    thedict[n] = thedict[n] + 1
    print(thedict[n])

print(newClass.class_dict)
```

will output

```
1
2
3
4
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}
```